# Using VLOOKUP referencing another sheet in VBA excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel

I know many questions have been both asked and answered around this subject, but I couldn't find anything that worked for me as I'm referencing another sheet (Lookuptable).

Below is the original VLOOKUP as written in excel, this works fine:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Lookuptable!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

Below is a stripped back **pseudo code** version of my script, with the VBA vlookup line of code that is providing the issue. I'm basically looking for the VBA version of the above that works!

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng2 As Range
    Dim arg4 As Boolean
    Dim arg1 As Long, arg3 As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

rng.Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(i, Sheets(Lookuptable).Range("A1:B1"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

It’s probably worth noting that I ether get a subscript out of range error or a invalid procedure call or argument error.

Comment: youre using `i` in the VLookup but `i` has not been assigned.

Comment: lookuptable is not assigned either

Comment: Sorry as mentioned "stripped back pseudo code", I only have included a snippet of my code that should hopefully be enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

        For i = 2 to rng.Rows.Count
            rng.Cells(i, 2) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Cells(i,1), Sheets("Lookuptable").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I now get an 'Invalid or unqualifyed reference' error, which highlights the .Cells(i, 1) part of the VLOOKUP

Comment: Is that part between the 'With ActiveSheet - End With' block? If not, try ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).